# Cancancan passing an object through ability check

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, user-roles, cancancan

I'm setting up an admin ability using Cancancan. I have an association where a room

`has_one :group, through: :property`

I'm aware that one can't pass an object through using cancancan, but we can check abilities by using a hash.

```
#ability.rb

if user.has_role?(:admin)    
  can :manage, Room, :group => { :id => user.group_id }  
end
```

The above ability check works when I'm loading my index, show, update, edit and destroy methods, but doesn't work when I'm loading the new or create methods. 
I know that Cancancan passes any conditions as a hash, like [this](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions#new-and-create-actions), but I don't think it's passing my hash because groups are set up as an association instead of a column on each room object.

```
#rooms_controller.rb

class RoomsController < ApplicationController 
  load_and_authorize_resource
    def new
      @room = Room.new
    end
end
```

My question is, how can I check this ability on new and create methods, preferably without adding new columns to my objects.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: When do you set what group a room belongs to?

Comment: It gets set up through a property on create. Each group has about 6 properties, and each property has about 10 rooms.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `load_and_authorize_resource`, you shouldn't be doing `@room = Room.new` in the `new` method. The `load_and_authorize_resource` method does that for you. So my assumption is you're overwriting the one it's initializing.

The same would apply to all of the other methods in `RoomsController`, unless you want to override how the image is loaded (eager loading, etc.) or searched for.

Comment: Even with `@room = Room.new` removed, I'm still having the same issue

Comment: Also, I should have added, your question states you want to check this ability in the new/create methods. But for new/create the `load_and_authorize` part is only initializing a the value and populating it w/the query params (in the case of create). B/c you said the user can manage `Rooms`, they can always create them. There is no real authorization (checking the group id) in this scenario.

Comment: But it is checking it on new and create.

Comment: When I have `can :manage, Room, :group => { :id => user.group_id }` it fails, but when i just have `can :manage, Room` it passes the check. But only on New and Create

Comment: `can :manage, Room` only checks if there is _any_ can rule that matches, it does _not_ check conditions. See https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/develop/docs/check_abilities_mistakes.md

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following.

To check against a rule with custom attributes the new object you create must have those attributes. i.e. a Room with the current user's group_id

```rb
#rooms_controller.rb

class RoomsController < ApplicationController 
  def new
    @room = Room.new(group_id: current_user.group_id)
    authorize! @room
  end
end
```

Alternatively I think you can specify custom params for an action via https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/develop/docs/changing_defaults.md#strong-parameters

So that *might* (I haven't tested) look like:

```rb
#rooms_controller.rb

class RoomsController < ApplicationController 
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def new
    puts @room
  end

  def room_params
    @room_params = params.require(:room).permit(:group_id)
    @room_params[:room].merge(group_id: current_user.group_id) # ??
    @room_params
  end
end
```

That said, you might not even want to restrict the *new* action, since the resource doesn't create anything, it might not matter who gets here.